# Deserialize SQL Server image field back in Excel format

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2012, deserialization

I have a SQL Server table that contains serialized Excel files, with 3 fields:

IdDocument -> int (PK)

DataFile -> image

FileName -> nvarchar

where DataFile contains the Excel file serialized, and FileName the name of the file (with path).

Something like this:

0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE100.....

U:\SAP_R3V4_Validation_Documents\March2012.xls

Now I need to get these files back in Excel format.

How can I accomplish this?

Using C# console application or SQL Server features could be fine.

Thank you in advance.

Luis

Comment: Excel files are binary. There's nothing to deserialize. You need to read that `varbinary(max)` field and write its contents to disk before you can use it. `image` is a deprecated type, replaced by `varbinary(max)` since 2005 or 2008. Have you tried writing any C# code that will read the contents of those fields?

Comment: To retrieve binary data you can use [SqlDataReader.GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.0) or [GeSqlBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbytes?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel files are binary. The `xls` format is obsolete, replaced since 2007 (15 years ago) by `xlsx`, a ZIP package containing XML files. What the question shows is how binary data looks in SSMS, not some kind of serialized format.

BTW the `image` is deprecated, replaced by `varbinary(max)` in 2005 or 2008 (can't remember).

In any case, reading binary data is the same as reading any other data. A DbDataReader is used to retrieve the query results and strongly typed methods are used to read specific fields per row. In this particular case [GetStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.0) can be used to retrieve the data as a Stream that can be saved to disk:

```
using var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    using (var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con))
    {
        using (var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                var path=reader.GetString(2);
                var finalPath=Path.Combine(root,Path.GetFileName(path))

                using(var stream=reader.GetStream(1))
                {
                    using(var fileStream=File.Create(finalPath))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The only thing that's different is the code that reads the field as a stream and saves it to disk

```
using(var stream=reader.GetStream(1))
{
    using(var fileStream=File.Create(finalPath))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

The `using` clauses are used to ensure the data and file streams are closed even in case of error. The path itself is constructed by combining a root folder with the stored filename, not the full path

Comment: Thank you very much Panagiotis. I have just to iterate through every Id and create a file for each of them.